# map lambda creating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this

```
[('h', ['ab', 'aus']), ('c', ['ab', 'escu']), ('n', ['lia', 'lmos'])]
```

I want this

```
[{'ab': 1, 'aus': 1}, {'ab': 1, 'escu': 1}, {'lia': 1, 'lmos': 1}]
```

I tried

```
map(lambda row: [{b: 1 } for b in row[1]])
```

results

```
[[{‘ab': 1}, {'aus': 1}], [{'ab': 1}, {'escu': 1}], [{'lia': 1}, {'lmos': 1}]]
```

Can you help me to correct my map function?

Comment: Will the lists inside your tuples contain duplicates?

Answer (score 8):

A `map` is not the right function to use here. What if your lists contain more than one of the same item? I'd recommend using a `Counter` instead.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [dict(Counter(y)) for _, y in data]
[{'ab': 1, 'aus': 1}, {'ab': 1, 'escu': 1}, {'lia': 1, 'lmos': 1}]
```

If your list sub-items are unique, you may instead go for `dict.fromkeys`.

```
>>> [dict.fromkeys(y, 1) for _, y in data]
[{'ab': 1, 'aus': 1}, {'ab': 1, 'escu': 1}, {'lia': 1, 'lmos': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 's answer. But to get what you wanted with a lambda function, you were actually pretty close:

```
row = [('h', ['ab', 'aus']), ('c', ['ab', 'escu']), ('n', ['lia', 'lmos'])]
e = list(map(lambda x: {b:1 for b in x[1]}, row))
print(e)
```

Output:

```
[{'ab': 1, 'aus': 1}, {'ab': 1, 'escu': 1}, {'lia': 1, 'lmos': 1}]
```

Notice the `{}` notation in the for loop: [dict comprehension syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).